# rEFInd deleted after formatting Mac OS X partition

Tags: mac, refind

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro 9,2 , I installed it side by side with Mac OS X, and used rEFInd to boot into ubuntu, then I have decided to use the Mac OS X partition as my home folder in ubuntu, so I formatted it and moved my home folder into the new formatted partition, to discover after restarting the computer that the rEFInd loader was formatted with the partition, I was able to boot again into ubuntu by installing rEFInd on a flash drive and booting from it, I have tried to install rEFInd again through ubuntu using the install.sh file but was unsuccessful too, it gives me the following message:

```
Installing rEFInd on Linux....

ESP was found at /boot/efi using vfat

Found rEFInd installation in /boot/efi/EFI/refind; upgrading it.

Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)

Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.

An existing rEFInd boot entry exists, but isn't set as the default boot
manager. The boot order is being adjusted to make rEFInd the default boot
manager. If this is NOT what you want, you should use efibootmgr to
manually adjust your EFI's boot order.
Installing it!

ALERT: There were problems running the efibootmgr program! You may need to
rename the refind_x64.efi binary to the default name (EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
on x86-64 systems or EFI/boot/bootia32.efi on x86 systems) to have it run!
Existing //boot/refind_linux.conf found; not overwriting.

ALERT:
Installation has completed, but problems were detected. Review the output for
error messages and take corrective measures as necessary. You may need to 
re-run this script or install manually before rEFInd will work.
```

and now all I have when normally booting my mac is the recovery system, and when I press alt I get the windows option but not successful in booting into it..
please help! and sorry for my english

- Note: I also tried changing the file name into bootx64.efi and it didn't work either

Comment: Did you try deleting all the refind files and installing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems to me that I have followed the correction procedure in the output in a wrong way, this is what I did and worked for me:

First install rEFInd using the install.sh file

Secondly Copy all the contents of the refind folder into a new created boot folder, this command will do it:

Sudo cp -a /boot/efi/EFI/refind/. /boot/efi/EFI/boot/

Thirdly rename the refind_x64.efi binary into the default name as suggested in the output:

sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/boot/refind_x64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi

The last thing to do is to make the refind boot option the startup disc, this could be done by pressing alt at the computer start to show the different options available, and then pressing ctrl while selecting the refind disc..